# Retrieving JTable inputted data by columns as an array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I have made a `JTable` with preset values `Miscitems` and `Miscdata:`

```
String [] Miscitems = {"Card Table", "Chair, Folding", "Fan", "Filing Cabinet, 2drs", "Filing Cabinet, 4drs", "Hamper", 
                               "Heater", "Ironing Board", "Plant Pots", "Plant Stand/Pillars", "Statues", "Suitcase", "Trunk"};
Object [] Miscdata = {2, 1, 3, 10, 20, 5, 5, 2, 2, 10, 3, 5, 10};
```

and with one array that users can change (where there wasn't an original value):

```
Object [] Misccount = new Object [Miscitems.length];
```

Here is the code for the actual table:

```
DefaultTableModel Miscmodel = new DefaultTableModel();
       Miscmodel.addColumn("Item", Miscitems);
       Miscmodel.addColumn("Volume of Item (Cubic Feet)", Miscdata);
       Miscmodel.addColumn("Input Amount of Item", Misccount);
  JTable Misctable = new JTable(Miscmodel);
  JPanel panel7 = new JPanel();
       panel7.add(Misctable);
       panel7.add(new JScrollPane(Misctable));
```

What is the best way to retrieve the changed data in array form? (Which is in its own column) and is there an easy way to change that data into an `int[][]` array? Also, will data left blank by users simply come out as zero in `Misccount?`

Comment: *"Also, will data left blank by users simply come out as zero in Misccount?"* it will likely be `null` but you should check it

Comment: `DefaultTableModel#getValueAt` is where you want to start

Comment: to add to the above answer, type of data will depend on type you declare for your data. And yes, make the table editable also.